# Do Facebook graph API v2.0 results map to v1.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

How can I get app-scoped ids for users who haven't logged in to app - specifically for ids of logged in users' friends?

This is the use case:

- App is on v1.0 currently.
- User A logged in to the app and I got a fbId_a, along with user's friend B fbId_b (these are not app scoped Id's and b is not an app user).

When I migrate to v2.0 if B joins I will get an appscoped id for B fbId_b_appscoped. How do I ascertain fbId_b_appscoped is the same as fbId_b present in my database?

Is there a one to one mapping between fbId_b_appscoped and fbId_b? If so, what's the API for it?

Comment: This is NOT possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can't - if you stored a user's list of friends under v1.0 (or by checking the commenters or likes on a post, something like that ) and later one of those friends authorises your app under v2.0 you'll get an app scoped ID for the friend, you can't correlate that to the IDs you obtained elsewhere

There's more information about how App Scoped IDs work and how to corelate users across multiple apps owned by your business here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Comment: So what will happen to the data I kept collecting till now ? . In the future if FB api's get updated with app scoped id's I won't be able to do anything with the data ???